# How to make Gnome Blank Screen/Auto Suspend to LightDM

Tags: gnome, lightdm, 17.10, gnome-shell, display-manager

I have Ubuntu Studio 17.10 which comes with XFCE and LightDM preinstalled. I decided to install Gnome 3 but did not want to use GDM as I prefer LightDM.

My problem is that now when I use my Gnome session it wont black the screen after a while or lock out to the LightDM login screen, it just stays showing my Gnome desktop constantly. I have attempted to change this in Gnome Settings as well as in the LightDM GTK+ Greeter Settings but to no avail. I even set it to black screen/lock after 1 minute just to test it and nothing would work.

Here are the version numbers for the installed software:

Ubuntu Studio 17.10

Gnome Shell 3.26.1

LightDM 1.24.0

As requested here is an image of my Power settings, as well as an image of the LightDM settings.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this is an easy fix, thanks in advance.

Comment: include a screen-shot of your power settings.

Comment: Added,  and a screenshot of the LightDM settings if thats useful too.

Comment: @Legolas just a bump, I uploaded screenshots. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, you found a fix?

Comment: @sticsk not yet

Comment: Yeah I asked the same question though, I made LightDM work when I reboot my PC, but when I hit Super + L (to lock it) I won't get LightDM and it's super annoying